# Unity raycast going random directions

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine

```
Ray r = new Ray(this.transform.position, this.transform.eulerAngles);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(r, out hit, 3000, 256 /*layer 8*/ )){
```

That little bit of code won't give me a forward raycast, and I've searched for a number of solutions over multiple hours, to no avail.

So, the above won't give me a straight raycast out the front of the object and I don't know why. I figure it's probably an oversight.

Comment: Why not use "transform.forward" instead of "this.transform.eulerAngles"?

Comment: There are multiple things wrong here. eulerAngles will not yield the same results as a direction vector. eulerAngles of (0,180,0) will probably give a direction of (0,0,-1) or similar. Also, the ray is cast in world space by default. So first get the direction by saying Vector3 dir = target.transform.pos - this.transform.position and use that as the direction parameter.

Comment: @Reasurria I don't see any reason to assume a `target` exists. Q asks for a "straight raycast out the front of the object". But you are right about the first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor for [`Ray`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ray-ctor.html) takes an **origin** and a **direction**. [`transform.eulerAngles`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) returns a vector of three **angles** around the `x`, `y`, and `z` axes. "Direction" might sound similar to angles, but it's not: the angles are rotation, not direction. The important distinction is that a direction vector "points" a certain way, but rotation describes how something is oriented. You could create a direction vector *using* the rotation information, but fortunately Unity can do this for you.

The easiest way to fix this is to use Unity's built-in way to get an object's forward direction vector (as seen in the `Ray` doc):

```
// Create a ray from the transform position along the transform's z-axis
Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
```

[`transform.forward`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) gives you the forward direction vector of `transform`, meaning that the ray will be shot in the direction the object's facing.

Comment: Answer is correct. I knew I was doing something very scrubbish, which is pathetic given my good deal of experience with Unity. I was using Vector3.forward instead of transform.forward 9_9. But thank you for taking the time to make it more clear in my mind what to do in this situation, because it will probably help me remember better in the future.